Was it OK for contractors to cut this diagonal brace?
In preparation for adding plywood shear walls to our basement cripple walls (for seismic retrofits), our contractors removed a portion of an original diagonal brace, as shown in the before/after photos below. They added a new cripple stud along the cut in the diagonal brace, and nailed through the cripple stud face into the cut end of the brace.
The diagonal brace runs behind our chimney, so we have no access the the rest of it. They plan to put plywood bracing that ends at their new cripple stud. Will the new plywood be sufficient to replace the role that the diagonal brace was playing, or is there something I should ask the contractor to do in order to make this right?
For context, this is a multi-story Victorian house in California.
Before, showing the brace intact (along with a cripple stud that they cut at the wrong angle, since the diagonal brace is not close to 45°):

After, showing the cut brace:


I would think that if the plywood extends beyond the new stud and is nailed to the original diagonal bracing that you'd be OK, but if you're really concerned, point it out to the inspector while he's there.
